# Use a custom currency symbol for a DataGridView column?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, currency, currency-formatting

I want to format a DataGridView column which shows money values, however I want to use a custom currency prefix, which is not currently defined by any culture. I want my values to look like this:

```
Mn. 2,300.00
Mn. 40,259.22
Mn. 6.33
Mn. 2,000,203.19
```

Obviously, `Mn.` is the prefix I want to add. Other than this customization, the value itself is to be formatted like any other currency (i.e. 2 decimal places, commas after every 3 digits, etc ..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to manage your own `NumberFormatInfo` object, which contains a `CurrencySymbol` property.  You can pass this object to the `decimal.ToString()` method.

```
var format = (NumberFormatInfo)NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.Clone();
format.CurrencySymbol = "Mn. ";
var amount = 12345.67m;
Console.WriteLine(amount.ToString("C", format));
```

Comment: I'm trying to use your code to define the CellCstyle for a column in a DataGridView, however I still get the default system currency symbol, and not my custom one. I tried the following code:  

  
`var format = (NumberFormatInfo)NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.Clone();  
format.CurrencySymbol = "Mn. ";  
qBDDataGridView.Columns["Based Selling Price"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = String.Format("n", format);  
qBDDataGridView.Columns["Based Selling Price"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c";`

Comment: Nevermind, found the solution:

`var format = (NumberFormatInfo)NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.Clone();  
format.CurrencySymbol = "Mn. ";  
qBDDataGridView.Columns["Based Selling Price"].DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = format;  
qBDDataGridView.Columns["Based Selling Price"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c";  `

Answer (score 4):

*(This self-answer was previously posted by the question OP as an edit to the question. Content migrated to this answer.)*

```
var format = (NumberFormatInfo)NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.Clone();  
format.CurrencySymbol = "Mn. ";  
qBDDataGridView.Columns["Base Selling Price"].DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = format;  
qBDDataGridView.Columns["Base Selling Price"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c";
```

The above will format a column named `"Base Selling Price"` in that `DataGridView` to use the custom symbol `'Mn.'` for the currency. Hope this proves to be useful to others too. Credit goes to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14014114/4298200) by [Jason Whitted](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1910843/jason-whitted) 
 which led me (the question OP) in the right direction.